# Process builder rule criteria

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I am trying to use below condition to update title field on contact in process builder but it is not working.

```
AND(
(PRIORVALUE([Contact].Account.AccountNumber),"t"),
ISNULL([Contact].Title),
ISCHANGED([Contact].AccountId))
```

It is giving me error: The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing ')'

No Matter I add how many ')'

Comment: your formula looks wrong. Can you please explain what you want to try?

Comment: I want to check if prior value of account number on account is 't', contact's title is null and AccountId is changed then title becomes TEST.

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula if it works for you:

```
AND
(
   PRIORVALUE([Contact].Account.AccountNumber) = 't',
   ISNULL( [Contact].Title ),
   ISCHANGED( [Contact].AccountId )
)
```

You need to compare with `=` sign.

Comment: Seems like `PRIORVALUE()` don't work with relationship field.. `[Contact].Account.AccountNumber`

Comment: It will not work with = sign as well.

Comment: @Ratan - Yes seems like PRIORVALUE will not work with relationship field.

Comment: @sfdcrowdy yes, autonumber can not have prior value as it is not writable

Comment: @Ashwani - I think AccountNumber is a text field, so do you mean that it will work for Text field but not for Autonumnber field. If yes, then how?? Can you please guide here.

Answer (score 0):

Once Check that if you Checked the Recursion Checkbox and if it is checked, Read the Below point.

1) Cannot use the functions like ISCHANGED, ISNEW or PRIORVALUE in the process criteria, if the advanced options like Recursion is checked in the Object node.